# Increase canvas size on a drawing in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the drawing tool in google sheets to create a flowchart. My flowchart requires more space than the standard canvas size. How can increase the canvas size?

I could not find an option to adjust the ruler. I also could not find an option to add the shapes for the flowchart direction on the sheet, I had to go through the drawing tool.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  Consider asking [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets).  Good luck!